# Probability of drawing a certain card given other 6 (unknown) have been drawn

Tags: probability, probability-theory, card-games

I have the following question to answer:

> Cards are drawn at random, without replacement, from a well-shuffled pack  of 52 cards.
>
> - 12 cards are dealt with six face down and the others being a jack, 
>     two kings, a 7, and two 3s.
>     If a 13th card is dealt, what is the probability that it will be a 2,          3 or 4?

Since I do not know the value of the first 6 cards, I thought that the most I can do is just giving an interval of the probability of my event.
However, it seems that since I haven't seen the first 6 cards, this does not change the probability. Hence,

$$\left(\frac{4}{46}\right) + \left(\frac{2}{46}\right) + \left(\frac{4}{46}\right) = \left(\frac{10}{46}\right) = \left(\frac{5}{23}\right)$$

I am now pretty sure to be wrong. And even if I were right, I would appreciate if someone could make this whole idea of "not changing the probability" more clear.

Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Comment: That's right, the cards you don't know the identity of can be any of the remaining unseen cards.  Therefore you calculate as if you are selecting from any of the unseen cards.

Comment: Close: there are $46$ unknown cards, so your result should be $\frac{10}{46}=\frac{5}{23}$

Comment: This seems to make sense indeed. So I treat the unrevealed cards as if there were still in the deck (?). 
I tweaked the answer above, is it right now?

Comment: It follows a similar line of logic as how the probability that when drawing two cards in sequence that the second card is a queen is equal to the probability that the first card is a queen, or indeed having drawn $n$ cards that the $n$'th is a queen is the same as the probability that the first is a queen.  The short handwavy proof is that the available cards are all equally likely to be in the position of interest, even if that position is not the first position.